# phpMyadmin login failure

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am new to WP.I start the WP locally
i need help regarding this issue,i am unable to login to my phpmyadmin.Credentials are incorect,from where i get those credentials..
i tried with root but failure ahead as always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an issue with my config.inc.php, So i re-install the wamp server, and it works great to me,,

Answer (score 2):

It may be that the password for phpMyAdmin has been changed. To fix this issue go to your phpMyAdmin folder and look for the file config.inc.php.

Inside this file look for the following entries:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';      // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'root';      // MySQL password
```

Make sure that both user and password are set to *root*.

Comment: but there is no any type of  code in my file. when i am trying to add this the local host keep loading,,can you provide me the fresh copy of the config file or way to get this.

Comment: i think there is something wrong with my config file

Answer (score 1):

Refer these links, It will help you to reset your password:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_password